# Was David Ben-Gurion's marriage to Paula in December 1917 in New York?

Tags: israel

I have been trying to find a document online to support the statement that David Ben-Gurion's marriage to Paula Munweis (spelling varies) was in December 1917.  If the document is available, but the date is inaccurate, I would appreciate the correct information.

Answer (score 3):

[FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/) has this record in the [New York City Marriages](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:24QY-TLX?print=true) file.  It lists the date as 05 Dec 1917.

```
Name:   David G. Ben-Gurion
Titles and Terms:   
Event Type: Marriage
Event Date: 05 Dec 1917
Event Place:    Manhattan, New York, New York, United States
Event Place (Original): Manhattan, New York
Registration Date:  
Registration Year:  
Registration Place: 
Gender: Male
Age:    31
Marital Status: Single
Previous Wife's Name:   
Race:   White
Birth Date: 1886
Birth Year (Estimated): 
Birthplace: Plonsk, Russia
Father's Name:  Victor Ben-Gurion
Father's Titles and Terms:  
Father's Birthplace:    
Father's Age:   
Mother's Name:  Shende
Mother's Titles and Terms:  
Mother's Birthplace:    
Mother's Age:   
Paternal Grandfather's Name:    
Paternal Grandmother's Name:    
Maternal Grandfather's Name:    
Maternal Grandmother's Name:    
Spouse's Name:  Pauline C. Moonvess
Spouse's Titles and Terms:  
Spouse's Gender:    Female
Spouse's Age:   25
Spouse's Marital Status:    Single
Spouse's Previous Husband's Name:   
Spouse's Race:  White
Spouse's Birth Date:    1892
Spouse's Birth Year (Estimated):    1892
Spouse's Birthplace:    Minsk, Russia
Spouse's Father's Name: Samuel Moonvess
Spouse's Father's Titles and Terms: 
Spouse's Mother's Name: Bertha Block
Spouse's Mother's Titles and Terms: 
Spouse's Paternal Grandfather's Name:   
Spouse's Paternal Grandmother's Name:   
Spouse's Maternal Grandfather's Name:   
Spouse's Maternal Grandmother's Name:   
Note:   
Reference ID:   cn 17000
GS Film Number: 1643037
Frame Number:   



Citing this Record:
"New York, New York City Marriage Records, 1829-1940," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:24QY-TLX : 20 March 2015), David G. Ben-Gurion and Pauline C. Moonvess, 05 Dec 1917; citing Marriage, Manhattan, New York, New York, United States, New York City Municipal Archives, New York; FHL microfilm 1,643,037.
```

This question belongs on the [genealogy page](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/), however.